# angular + ui-router : event.preventDefault(); prevent all the app states from working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I want to evaluate the user when the app start if it's authenticated change the state to "categories" if not go to "land" state. i reached this using `$stateChangeStart` in the `run` block like so :

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, DSCacheFactory, $rootScope, $auth, $state) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }

    });
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {
            if (!$auth.isAuthenticated() && toState.name !== 'land') {
                event.preventDefault(); 
                $state.go('land');
            }
        });
})
```

and like this if it's authenticated:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('app/categories');
```

every thing works fine user get evaluated correctly but, clicking on anything in the app taking me to the `land` state. Any idea why!
The router code :

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $authProvider, $ionicAppProvider, API_URL) {
    $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
        url: "/app",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })

    .state('land', {
        url: '/land',
        templateUrl: 'templates/land.html',
        controller: 'LandCtrl'
    })

.state('signup', {
        url: '/sign-up',
        templateUrl: 'templates/sign-up.html',
        controller: 'SignUpCtrl'
    })

    .state('signin', {
        url: '/sign-in',
        templateUrl: 'templates/sign-in.html',
        controller: 'SignInCtrl'
    })

    .state('app.categories', {
        url: '/categories',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/categories.html',
                controller: 'categoriesCtrl',
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why do you need  event.preventDefault() ?

Comment: if i didn't it take me to the categories state which is the otherwise

Comment: Can you post your router code ?

Comment: Done, sorry for late reply time differences.